# Python string split

Tags: python

what would be the best way to split this in python. (address, city, state, zip)

```
<div class="adtxt">7616 W Belmont Ave<br />Chicago, IL 60634-3225</div>
```

in some case zip code is as

```
 <div class="adtxt">7616 W Belmont Ave<br />Chicago, IL 60634</div>
```

Comment: It's easy to give an approach for this specific example, but you'll get a better answer if you explain what kinds of addresses you need to handle, and what assumptions you're making. For example: Can there be more than one address line? Do you have to handle international addresses? Is it possible for state/zip to be on different lines? Will <br /> be the only way to separate lines? Etc. etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on how tight or lax you want to be on various aspects that can't be deduced from a single example, something like the following should work...:

```
import re

s = re.compile(r'^<div.*?>([^<]+)<br.*?>([^,]+), (\w\w) (\d{5}-\d{4})</div>$')
mo = s.match(thestring)
if mo is None:
  raise ValueError('No match for %r' % thestring)
address, city, state, zip = mo.groups()
```

Comment: obligatory: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: the works fine, but if the zip is only 5 digits, it throws error

Comment: replace `(\d{5}-\d{4})` at the end of regexp with `(\d{5}-\d{4}|\d{5})`

Comment: @bobsr, I _do_ explain it depends on how strict or lax you want to be on conditions that are impossible to deduce from a single example -- if the only variation (as per your edit) is in the zipcode, @cji's solution fixes that; if there's more variation, you need more and more tweaks.

Comment: And BTW, I agree that the parsing of the tag themselves could best be done by an HTML parser, but if you do that you still need further processing for the city / state / zip separation.

Answer (score 0):

Just a hint: there are much better ways to parse HTML than regular expressions, for example [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

[Here's why you shouldn't do that with regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

EDIT: Oh well, @teepark linked it first. :)

Answer (score 0):

Combining beautifulsoup and the regular expressions should give you something like:

```
import BeautifulSoup
import re
thestring = r'<div class="adtxt">7616 W Belmont Ave<br />Chicago, IL 60634-3225</div>'
re0 = re.compile(r'(?P<address>[^<]+)')
re1 = re.compile(r'(?P<city>[^,]+), (?P<state>\w\w) (?P<zip>\d{5}-\d{4})')
soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(thestring)
(address,) = re0.search(soup.div.contents[0]).groups()
city, state, zip = re1.search(soup.div.contents[2]).groups()
```

Comment: this works fine, but if the zip is only 5 digits (60634), it throws error